# I need to make an automated 3d dictionary in python

Tags: python

I'm given a .csv file with three data separated by comma.

For example, the data looks like this:

```
   transaction, client, amount
   1,1,10.50
   2,1,3.0
   3,1,2.75
   4,2,90.0
   5,3,25.0
   6,3,0.05
```

I need to make a dictionary so that the output would be something like this:

```
    {1: {1: 10.50, 2: 3.0, 3: 2.75}, 2: {4: 90.0}, 3: {5: 25.0, 6: 0.05}}
```

Also, is there any way to do it with a loop or a built in function similar to map? Note, that the second column of each line is supposed to be the main key.

Thanks in advance. I'm going crazy trying to figure it out!

Comment: Post your attempt please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write in a way it should be easier for you to understand by using the CSV module.

```
import csv

new_dict = {}

with open("your_csv_file.csv","r",newline="") as f:
    result = csv.reader(f)
    next(result, None)
    for row in result:
        transaction = int(row[0])
        client = int(row[1])
        amount = float(row[2])
        if client in new_dict:
            new_dict[client][transaction] = amount
        else:
            new_dict[client] = {transaction:amount}

print (new_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'1': {'1': '10.5', '2': '3', '3': '2.75'}, '2': {'4': '90'}, '3': {'5': '25', '6': '0.05'}}
```

Comment: Henry Yik, you saved my life!

Comment: I edited it a bit since i realize you wanted int/floats as result. If it works, try to make it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

filename = "test.csv"
with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader, None)  # Skip header

    data = defaultdict(dict)
    for transaction, client, amount in reader:
        data[int(client)][int(transaction)] = float(amount)

data = dict(data)
print(data)
```